# How to remove the hash tag from this regex

Tags: regex

My current regex:

```js
(\d.{17})[^#]*(\D+)(\d+)gr(\d+)
```

In group 2, they are still having the hashtag, I want to remove it from there. What should I change from my current regex?

```
201223E0MWJPJD2230#AdeSaputra290gr99000
2101023CNV6TT1109J#Fefe430gr142000
2101183EDTFPSA0128#Jessica500gr112000
201221E2QKWRY11413#EssyYosita880gr233500
2101123G9XQ7R41705#Meily1120gr329000
201228ECEWTJT50859#WidyaNatali1720gr457230
201227EEBX1K9K1020#Excelio112gr58900
2101112N4YNFB12016#DebyNath520gr156220
2101072R8A0QB22347#AlycieHandoTan700gr85000
```

Output:

```
group 1: 201223E0MWJPJD2230
group 2: #AdeSaputra
group 3: 290
group 4: 99000
```

Comment: `(\d.{17})#?(\D+)(\d+)gr(\d+)` or `(\d.{17})#(\D+)(\d+)gr(\d+)`

Comment: It seems like `[^#]` should just be `[#]`. Why are you skipping over non-hashtags if you really want to skip over hashtags?

Comment: If possible, could you kindly upvote my answer? Since it works, and you have now [enough reputation for this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\D` matches any non-digits and it matches `#` in your input.

Add `#` to the pattern instead of the opposite `[^#]` so as to match it.

Use

```
^(\d.{17})#(\D+)(\d+)gr(\d+)$
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/SHPNWM/1) it works. Adding anchors to match entire strings.

**Explanation**

```php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .{17}                    any character except \n (17 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  #                        '#'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \D+                      non-digits (all but 0-9) (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \3:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  gr                       'gr'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \4:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \4
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Answer (score 1):

remove `[^]` from your regex

```
(\d.{17})#*(\D+)(\d+)gr(\d+)
```

[see this](https://regex101.com/r/EEVVkK/1)